# How do I prevent ui-grid from resizing columns when filtering?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm having an issue where filtering in a ui-grid causes the column widths to be reset. I've saved grid state to local storage, and the issue only occurs on the first load, before any columns have been manually resized. After a column has been manually resized, filtering no longer causes the column width to be reset.

Plinker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/LAMZvOkpx6jsD4CWSz04?p=preview

(also referenced in this post: [angular ui grid save and restore state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32346341/angular-ui-grid-save-and-restore-state))

```
'use strict';

angular.module('grid-demo', [
  'LocalStorageModule',
  'ui.grid',
  'ui.grid.selection',
  'ui.grid.resizeColumns',
  'ui.grid.autoResize',
  'ui.grid.moveColumns',
  'ui.grid.grouping',
  'ui.grid.saveState',
])
.config(function ($httpProvider, localStorageServiceProvider) {
  localStorageServiceProvider
    .setPrefix('grid-demo')
    .setStorageType('localStorage')
    .setNotify(true, true); // Not sure what this setting does
})

.controller('MainCtrl', function ($rootScope, $scope, $http, $window, $timeout, uiGridConstants, localStorageService) {

  $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: [
      { name: 'Jack', title: 'manager', phone: '123456789', location: 'india'},
      { name: 'Suzy', title: 'developer', phone: '465189798', location: 'usa'},
      { name: 'George', title: 'secretary', phone: '82656517', location: 'japan'},
      { name: 'Michael', title: 'analyst', phone: '31321687', location: 'egypt'},
      { name: 'Sara', title: 'consultant', phone: '59595847', location: 'germany'},
      { name: 'Chris', title: 'engineer', phone: '789456123', location: 'russia'},
      { name: 'Elizabeth', title: 'clerk', phone: '963852741', location: 'china'},
      { name: 'Jane', title: 'intern', phone: '147258369', location: 'australia'},
      { name: 'Bill', title: 'accountant', phone: '951487623', location: 'brazil'}
    ],
    columnDefs: [
      { name: 'name' },
      { name: 'title' },
      { name: 'phone' },
      { name: 'location' }
    ],
    enableGridMenu: true,
    enableRowSelection: true,
    enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
    enableColumnResizing: true,
    enableColumnReordering: true,
    enableFiltering: true,
    onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
      // Keep a reference to the gridApi.
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;

      // Setup events so we're notified when grid state changes.
      $scope.gridApi.colMovable.on.columnPositionChanged($scope, saveState);
      $scope.gridApi.colResizable.on.columnSizeChanged($scope, saveState);
      $scope.gridApi.grouping.on.aggregationChanged($scope, saveState);
      $scope.gridApi.grouping.on.groupingChanged($scope, saveState);
      $scope.gridApi.core.on.columnVisibilityChanged($scope, saveState);
      $scope.gridApi.core.on.filterChanged($scope, saveState);
      $scope.gridApi.core.on.sortChanged($scope, saveState);

      // Restore previously saved state.
      restoreState();
    }
  };

  function saveState() {
    var state = $scope.gridApi.saveState.save();
    localStorageService.set('gridState', state);
  }

  function restoreState() {
    $timeout(function() {
      var state = localStorageService.get('gridState');
      if (state) $scope.gridApi.saveState.restore($scope, state);
    });
  }

});

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/release/3.0.6/ui-grid.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-local-storage/0.2.2/angular-local-storage.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/release/3.0.6/ui-grid.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-app="grid-demo" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
          <div ui-grid="gridOptions"
               ui-grid-selection 
               ui-grid-resize-columns 
               ui-grid-auto-resize 
               ui-grid-move-columns 
               ui-grid-grouping 
               ui-grid-save-state>
          </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Load the plinker
2. change a column's width
3. hit the little refresh button on the html preview (right side of plinker)
4. note that your column width change has been saved
5. click into any filter field and start typing
6. note that the columns widths are reset

It really appears that the filterChange event in ui-grid is notifying the grid to refresh, and once it does, it reloads from the original column definitions. However, I'm at a loss for find a way to prevent this.

Any suggestions would be warmly welcomed!

Comment: any updates on this? Having the same issue. Thanks!

Comment: unfortunately, no. I've given up for now, no one from the ui-grid team seems responsive.

Answer (score 0):

you should call restore state after your data is loaded in grid, for example after http, xhr request

Comment: There is no request being made...I think this issue is more related to the filtering and default behavior in ui-grid.