# Is it possible to know if the angular ui-grid is in restore mode?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restore, angular-ui-grid, savestate

I use the save state feature that allows you to save the current look of the grid and restore it upon returning to the grid. During the restoring process these events will be fired :

```
gridApi.core.on.filterChanged 
gridApi.pagination.on.paginationChanged
gridApi.core.on.sortChanged
gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged
```

where I have some logic. I want to block invocation of this code while the restoring process is active.

Is it possible to know if the angular ui-grid is in restore mode?

Comment: According to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32486273/782358 there doesn't appear to be "a single event for grid state changes".

Comment: Yes, all of this events change the state of grid and the same events will be  fired by restoring event. Following this answer you're going to invoke SavState during the restoring process, that is what I want to block.